# how to remove empty line when read from file and sort the double linked list

Tags: java, sorting, java.util.scanner

1- there is  empty line when read the word from text file

example:

```
  output:
   catholicate 
   chymia

   sitosterol 
   Aries
```

2- i  save the word in double linked list  but it's not sorted  how  i can sort it  in Alphabetical Order in double linked list .

the method  but  i don't put  save method in double  linked list :

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

    Scanner input;
    try{
        input = new Scanner(new File(""));
        String c;
        int i=0 ;
        input.useDelimiter(" |:|,|\\.");

        while(input.hasNext()) {
            c=input.next();
            System.out.println(c);
        }
        input.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine` as below:

```
    String line = null;
    while(input.hasNextLine()) {
        line=input.nextLine();
        //print the line only when it has some characters
        if(line.length()>0){
          System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just check the `length of line`, if it is `0` then ignore it

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be making things complicated for your self.  You should think in terms of what is the least I need to do to make this work.  Making programs simple is not easy.

> there is empty line when read the word from text file

You have to add the lines to a linked list.  If you skip blank lines you will have "removed" them.

> i save the word in double linked list but it's not sorted how i can sort it in Alphabetical Order in double linked list .

If you are using LinkedList you can call `Collections.sort()` If you are using your own implementation of a linked list you need to give us the code for it.

Comment: I would just read one line at a time. Scanner is a better choice than StringTokenizer